# Block storage creation problems through softlayer cli

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Trying to provision block storage through the softlayer cli and I'm running into issues. Anybody aware of how to get past this?

```
slcli block volume-order --storage-type endurance --size 10 --tier 0.25 --os-type LINUX --location dal05 

Argument Error: Could not find price for disk space
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the least amount of space you can order is 20 GB. Updating the above command with the correct amount of space worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the spaces available for block endurance are:

**20, 40, 80, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 12000**

There is not a storage size of 10 GB